# Questions about Systm calls like fork() and pipe() in C

Tags: c, pipe

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<stdlib.h>
   #include<unistd.h>
   #include<sys/wait.h>
   #include<errno.h>

   int main(int argc, char **argv){
       int n = atoi(argv[1]);
       int superdaddy = getpid();
       int p[n+1][2];
       int i=0;
       int cpid,output;
       int result = 0;

       if(pipe(p[0])<0){
           perror("1");
           return 1;
       }
       if(pipe(p[n])<0){
           perror("2");
           return 1;
       }
       output = p[0][1];
       if(getpid()==superdaddy){
           if(write(p[0][1],&result,sizeof(result))<0){
               perror("3");
               return 1;
           }
           if(close(p[0][1])<0){
               perror("4");
               return 1;
           }
       }
       while(1){
           if(i==n){
               if(read(p[n-1][0],&result,sizeof(result)<0)){
                   perror("5");
                   return 1;
               }
               result++;
               output = p[n][1];
               if(write(output,&result,sizeof(result))<0){
                   perror("6");
                   return 1;
               }
               if(close(p[n-1][0])<0){
                   perror("7");
                   return 1;
               }
               if(close(p[n][1])<0){
                   perror("8");      
                   return 1;
               }
               break;
           }
           i++;
           cpid = fork();
           if(cpid==0){
               if(i==n)
                   continue;
               if(pipe(p[i])<0){
                   perror("9");
                   return 1;
               }
               if(read(p[i-1][0],&result,sizeof(result))<0){
                   perror("10");
                   return 1;
               }
               result++;
               output = p[i][1];
               if(write(output,&result,sizeof(result))<0){
                   perror("11");
                   return 1;
               }
               if(close(p[i-1][0])<0){
                   perror("12");
                   return 1;
               }

               if(close(p[i][1]<0)){
                   perror("13");
                   return 1;
               }
               continue;
           }
           else if(cpid<0){
               perror("14");
               return 1;
           }
           break;
       }

       if(getpid()==superdaddy){
           wait(NULL);
           if(read(p[n][0],&result,sizeof(result))<0){
               perror("15");
               return 1;
           }
           printf("Result: %d\n",result);
           if(close(p[n][0])<0){
               perror("16");
               return 1;
           }
       }
       return 0;
   }
```

The Program aims to read a number n from command line and then forks n child process and create n pipes. process `p0` will be parent of process `p1`, `p1` will be parent of `p2`, so and so on. One variable (named result here) will be passed through pipes, every time it is passed it will be added by 1. So the output should be n as well. Pipe `Fi` connects `Pi` and `P(i+1)`. Attached is my code.

When *n=1* or *n=2*, the program can output correctly, which is 1 and 2 correspondingly. However, when *n=3*, it gives me a bad file error at error 5. I have hand-tracked the code for the whole afternoon but got no idea what is wrong with it. Anyone could help? Appreciate it first!

Comment: I've removed the line numbers. Sorry for inconvenience caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when n=3, it gives me a bad file error at error 5.

This could be fixed by removing that `if(close(p[i][1]<0)){` in your code, because you need to read from `p[i][0]` in your last iteration, i.e.

```
if (i == n) {
    if(read(p[n-1][0],&result,sizeof(result)<0)){
        ...
    }
}
```

---

This is an implementation of your idea, I hope it may be helpful:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s N\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int pipes[n][2];
    int i, val;
    pid_t pid;

    val = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (pipe(pipes[i]) < 0) {
            perror("pipe");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (pid == 0) {
            close(pipes[i][1]);
            if (read(pipes[i][0], &val, sizeof(val)) != sizeof(val)) {
                perror("read");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            printf("C %d read %d\n", getpid(), val);

            val++;
        }
        else {
            close(pipes[i][0]);

            printf("P %d writes %d\n", getpid(), val);

            if (write(pipes[i][1], &val, sizeof(val)) != sizeof(val)) {
                perror("write");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) != pid) {
                perror("waitpid");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            printf("%d is going to leave.\n", getpid());
            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }
    }

    printf("%d is going to leave.\n", getpid());
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

---

Testing run:

```
$ ./a.out 3
P 2005 writes 0
C 2006 read 0
P 2006 writes 1
C 2007 read 1
P 2007 writes 2
C 2008 read 2
2008 is going to leave.
2007 is going to leave.
2006 is going to leave.
2005 is going to leave.
```

---

Explanation:

The frame of that code is `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { pipe(); fork(); }`, which means it will create `n` pipes, and `n` new processes. In each iteration, the parent will write to `pipes[i][1]` and child will read from `pipes[i][0]`. Eventually, it will create a process chain connected by a series of pipes, and a value is passed down from the first process to the last through that series of pipes.

Comment: how is it possible that 2008 can read 2 but cannot write 3? I mean if ur test data is for my code.

Comment: Also, your implementation is not really correct coz if the input is 3, the output should be 3, i.e there has to be a 3 written to pipe[3] and superdaddy will read from pipe[3] then output 3 as answer.

Comment: @AnbangLi The output is from my code, not yours. And my code is a reimplementation of your idea (according to my understanding, of course), not a fix version of your code.

Comment: @AnbangLi I believe my implementation is correct. Because the frame of that code is `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { pipe(); fork(); }`, which means it will create `n` pipes, and `n` new processes. In each iteration, the parent will write to `pipes[i][1]` and child will read from `pipes[i][0]`. Eventually, it will create a process chain connected by a series of pipes, and a value is passed down from the first process to the last through that pipe series.

Comment: Ok I believe u r right ,but do you have any idea why my program has that bug when n=3?

Comment: @AnbangLi Your question is answered at the beginning of my updated answer.